# Assign vector of children to vector of grandparents

Tags: c++

So I have the following classes:

```
class A {}
class B : public A {}
class C : public B {}
```

When I try do the following, I get an error:

```
vector<C*> v1; //already instantiated with a vector of pointers to C.
vector<A*>* v2 = &v1;
```

> error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from `'std::vector<_Ty> *'`
>   to `'std::vector<_Ty> *'` Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion
>   requires `reinterpret_cast`, C-style cast or function-style cast

If `C` is a descendant of `A`, why is this happening?

Comment: Because `vector<A *>` isn't base of `vector<C *>`?

Comment: Yes, C is a descendent of A does not imply that vector<C*> is a descendent of vector<A*>. C++ simply doesn't work like that. Perhaps you need to allocate a new vector and copy items one by one, or perhaps you should start with vector<A*> in the first place.

Comment: @Gerardo you can think of it in the way that it's just part of the name. For example, `vector<C*>` is like `vector_Cptr` and `vector<A*>` is like `vector_Aptr`. They are not related in any way, their names just happen to be a little similar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `C` is derived from `A`, `std::vector<C*>` isn't derived from `std::vector<A*>`, so you can't assign the address of an object of the former type to a pointer for the latter.

Imagine what would become possible if you could do this:

```
vector<A*>* v2 = &v1;

/* *v2 is declared as a vector<A*> so we can do this: */
v2->push_back(new B);

/* Now we have effectively added a pointer to a B object
   to the vector v1, which is supposed to be a vector of
   C objects only! */
```

However, of course the following is possible:

```
int main()
{
  std::vector<C*>  v1;
  std::vector<A*>  v2(begin(v1),end(v1));
  return 0;
}
```

Here, we create a new vector `v2` and copy the elements of `v1` into it. This is possible because `C` is derived from `A`.

Comment: I sense a most vexing parse... Nope, guess not, looks like C++ checks if `begin` and `end` are types or not.